# Google Analytics Event Tracking Filter not working when we have multiple filters

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, event-tracking

The metrics for my Query is as below:

```
ga:eventValue
```

The dimensions for my query is as below:

```
ga:eventLabel,ga:eventAction,ga:year,ga:month,ga:day,ga:hour,ga:minute
```

Now when I apply a filter with `ga:hour==13` then I get the results filtered out for `ga:hour=13` which is perfectly fine.

But When I query using multiple filters `ga:eventAction==xxx,ga:hour==13` the result is not displayed correctly. My expectation is that I should be getting the results where the hour is 13 and `eventAction=xxx` but it gives a lot more results.

How the filters work when we have multiple filters? What is the maximum number of filters allowed? Does always the filter needs to be a dimension or metric?

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Your filter (`ga:eventAction==xxx,ga:hour==13`) is using a comma to separate the two conditions. With GA filters, the comma is the logical `OR`. If you use a semicolon instead, that will be the logical `AND`, which should give you want you want.

You can read more on the filter syntax here. It should answer all your other questions:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters

Comment: @PhilipWalton One more query here. How to use OR Operator in filters/conditions? Instead of `a:eventCategory==Y,ga:eventCategory==Y`, I want to have it like - `ga:eventCategory==X|Y`.